# MYSQL how can i group field using conditionally statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL how can i group By ItemID only for Category = X and leave all others the same.

For example if i have JrnlHdr.Reference ='15027' && LineItem.Category = Laser and have which matches LineItem.ItemID= X1,X2,X3 i want group them by ItemID.

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Customers.CustomerID,
                Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, 
                Customers.WhichShipVia, 
                group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID) as ItemIDgroup,
                JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber,
                JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
                JrnlHdr.Comment, 
                JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
                JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, 
                JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, 
                JrnlHdr.Reference, 
                JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
                JrnlRow.DistNumber, 
                JrnlRow.Quantity, 
                LineItem.ItemID, 
                LineItem.SalesDescription, 
                LineItem.PartNumber,
                LineItem.Category, 
                LineItem.ItemClass, 
                LineItem.ItemDescription 
    FROM   Customers
           INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
           ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
           ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber =    Address.CustomerRecordNumber

          INNER JOIN JrnlRow
          ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
          LEFT OUTER JOIN BOMItems
          ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = BOMItems.AssemblyRecordNo
          INNER JOIN LineItem 
          ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber

       WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 
              AND LineItem.ItemID = '600331' 
              AND JrnlHdr.Reference ='15027'
              AND TransactionDate = '2014-12-1' 
              AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder 
              AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
              AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
              AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 
      GROUP BY LineItem.ItemID");
```

Comment: you can group on arbitrary expression. `group by mod(somefield,2)` would group on even/odd numbers.

Comment: You could do the grouping for the 1 set in a subquery, and then you can exclude the the 1 set from the top query.

Comment: @MarcB I have more than one `Catagory` i want to merge only if `Category="Laser"` how can let MYSQL know that?

Comment: `group by category=laser, category`?

Comment: Thanks @MarcB i edited like this `GROUP BY LineItem.ItemID AND (LineItem.Category='Laser', LineItem.Category)`. let me know if am wrong

Comment: the `,` bit will be a syntax error. probably want just `group by (itemid and category = laser), category` or whatever.